# How to pass a parameter to a callback function to make a new function?

Tags: c, callback

Suppose in C I have the following code:

```
int foo0(int a) { int b = 0; return a + b; }
int foo1(int a) { int b = 1; return a + b; }

...
registerCallback(foo0);
registerCallback(foo1);
```

I need to make two functions `foo0` and `foo1` to make the code work, although they shared the same structure. I want to write only one function `int foo(int a, int b) { return a + b;}` and pass parameters to "make" new functions like `foo0` and `foo1`. Is that possible?

Comment: http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/

Comment: The `registerCallback` and the calling code are expecting a function of specific signature, in your case of type `int(*callbackType)(int, int)` (I hope). There is no way you can pass it a function of different type, unless changing the callback functionality code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Aha, yeah that's true, I need to change my example a bit to make my point more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
int bar2(int a, int b) { return bar(a); }

...
registerCallback(bar2)
```